# "To rejoice" as a transitive verb

Tags: word-usage, transitivity

From the fourth sentence of the Edgar Allan Poe story 'The Oblong Box':

"…and among other names, I was rejoiced to see that of Mr Cornelius Wyatt…"

'Rejoiced' here is being used as a transitive verb, in a passive construction. The obvious parallel is with '…I was delighted to see…' which is the construction we'd expect now.

'Rejoice' isn't used as a transitive verb now. Can anyone suggest why a verb might lose its 'transitive capacity' over time? If 'delighted' has much the same meaning as 'rejoiced' has in the quote, why is 'delighted' still used exactly this way, but not 'rejoiced'?

Comment: ***Rejoice*** is both transitiva and intransitive: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rejoice -" ***I was rejoiced***" appears to be a literary expression which was more common in the  19th century - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+rejoiced+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20was%20rejoiced%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 that reference says [WITH OBJECT] archaic Cause joy to:
I love to rejoice their poor Hearts at this season.  'Archaic' means 'no longer in use'. So my question stands.

Comment: I agree, please see my comment on 19th c.   usage of the expression.  ***Delighted*** is an adjective in "I was delighted" : http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/delighted?q=delighted+

Comment: @Josh61 but the ngram raises an interesting question. If a particular usage becomes rare enough (but not extinct) is it still correct? If you'd asked me "Is 'was rejoiced' correct usage?" I'd have said 'no', but the ngram appears to show it in continuous but decreasing use. If you put something that is plainly wrong into ngram (e.g. 'I is laughed.') surely there will still be a few instances that show up?

Comment: Okay, 'I is laughed' doesn't get any hits, but 'I is' appears with increasing frequency. Is this the influence of Jamaican English, or is there some standard construction 'I is'?

Comment: …and 'he done' appears to have been in regular use for 100+ years.

Comment: Josh61 'I was delighted to see him' is the passive version of 'To see him delighted me.'

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, in "I was delighted to see.." the word "delighted" is an adjective, not a verb. As [Ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+rejoiced+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3), it was once common to use "rejoiced" as an adjective in the same construction, but this fell out of favor in the 20th century; this story was published in 1844, so the use of that expression is hardly surprising.

Comment: The adjective emerged from the past-participle. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rejoiced+me%2Crejoice+me%2Ci+was+rejoiced%2Ci+am+rejoiced&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3